# Flask AppBuilder - How how to handle some database variables having a slash

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-appbuilder

I am using the ModelView to present a table and allow it to be edited. Most of the time the content works.

If the value in a row is for example "10.0.0.1/24" then the route editing it would be: "127.0.0.1/nets/10.0.0.1/24" which is wrong and results in "Page not Found". I do not see any documentation on how to escape the slash inside a variable I get from the database.

Comment: i dont know what you want to achive, but since you are using db table modeling, you can use model object to load the data in table and filter/clean the data there itself.

Comment: I already load the data from the DB into a model and display it. The issue is that when I click edit on a record in the table it redirects me to /edit/<pk>. In this case the pk is "10.0.0.1/24" and flask complains that there is no registered route for /edit/10.0.0.1/24